# Finding all "A" tags with specific strings in the attribute href?

Tags: selenium, href

```
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("zipcode")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("zipcode")).SendKeys(zipcode);
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("Go")).Click();

            driver.FindElements(By.TagName("A").  //<---- ?????????
```

I have some Selenium API code that I started. I aim to get all the "A" tags with the string "alertsepy" and the sting "sevendwarves" in the attribute href and return all those elements into an array so I can do some further processing. I started the code but I am really not quite sure how to get all the way there yet. Does anyone know how to do this type of query with Selenium.

Kind Regards!

Comment: <a name="alertsepy" > </a>

$("a[name*=' + search_term + ']") ; ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use css selector:

```
IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href*=alertsepy],a[href*=sevendwarves]")
```

This query will return `a` nodes with `href` attribute that contains *alertsepy* **or** *sevendwarves* **or** both strings:

```
<a href="alertsepy.html" > </a>
<a href="sevendwarves.html" > </a>
<a href="http://sevendwarves.org/alertsepy.html" > </a>
```

Or you can use:

```
IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href*=alertsepy][href*=sevendwarves]")
```

This query will return `a` nodes with `href` attribute that contains *alertsepy* **and** *sevendwarves* strings:

```
<a href="http://sevendwarves.org/alertsepy.html" > </a>
```

For a list of generally available css selectors refer to [w3c css selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#selectors). For the list of available in Selenium query types refer to [Locating UI Elements](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#locating-ui-elements-webelements).

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> anchortaglist = driver.find Elements(By.Tag Name('a');
```

Comment: you will get all anchor tags in you web page