# How to get link name which comes after hovering on a particular link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the  link name of all the links present on a particular page, but some link get visible after hovering over a particular link, like there is a parent child relation between those links and Selenium WebDriver is unable to identify the link names for the child link.

Is there any possible way to get all the link names including the parent and the child?

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import mx4j.tools.remote.http.HTTPConnectionManager;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class SparshLink {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        String basePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String finalPath = basePath + "\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", finalPath);

        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://sparshv2/");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        List<WebElement> list;
        list = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println("Number of links : " + list.size());

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            URL url = new URL(list.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != 404) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i).getText() + "is working properly.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(list.get(i).getText() + "is not working properly.");
            }
            connection.disconnect();


        }
    }

}
```

I'm sorry i wont be able to share the code behind the application.

Answer (score 0):

'a' will be the tag but I believe all your URL should be there in href attribute.

You should refer below:-

[Finding all "A" tags with specific strings in the attribute href?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370030/finding-all-a-tags-with-specific-strings-in-the-attribute-href)

Comment: thats what i have done taken all the href attribute and passed it to URL instance.